# Terraform AzureRM Azure API Managment creates stv1 instead stv2

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

I've created Azure API Managment with terraform. Now I read that Microsoft is retiring stv1 in 2024. I'm wondering why my API Management instances that were created mid 2022 do not have stv2 as default?

Is there a way to tell AzureRM Provider which Azure Rest API it should use ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/compute-infrastructure#how-do-i-migrate-to-the-stv2-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following image explains what is implemented on the Rest API page.
In my case, I did not specify a public_ip_address_id or zones in terraform.
Unfortunately the provider didn't indicate this somehow and the parameter is also optional.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/compute-platform-versions-for-azure-api-management-service/ba-p/2836971
[image: techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/…]

Comment: I just spent 45 minutes creating APIM only for it to be created as stv1!
Immediately found out that it was due to PIP from this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway#:~:text=API%20Management%20stv2%20requires%20a%20public%20IP%20with%20a%20unique%20DomainNameLabel%3A

Still wanted to confirm it and here I am! 
Terraform doc should have a mention of that.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @djflocko, if you deploy with a PIP for APIM, it will not use stv1.  Without the PIP, it will use stv1.  A bit problematic because reason leads you to not using a PIP... since you're doing an "Internal" deployment.

EDIT: The architecture of APIM is that it basically has a publicly facing API for the management of the APIM gateways.  This always needs a public IP address and is never deployed inside of your VNET, regardless of a normal deployment or VNET External/Internal deployments.  This does create some odd challenges.  The other part of APIM is a VM Scale Set (unless doinng self-managed gateways); so a load balancer and then a set of VMs behind that vIP.  The VM Scale Set is deployed on the VNET when doing a VNET deployment.

In my view the solution has some deficiencies that aren't well documentented.  One thing that is documented is that a VNET Internal deployment "breaks" the "Testing" tab within an API, because that management service isn't inside your network and cannot talk to the gateways (the gateways, which are the VM Scale Set, pull their configuration information) directly, for many aspects other than triggering updates.  Also, the import of a schema via URL cannot work with a VNET Internal deployment for the same reason (and there is zero documentation on that).  This could be fixed by leveraging a Service Bus for the management API to dump requests and the gateways can read the bus for operations to perform, like asking the gateways to perform a test or import a schema via URL, and then returning the response to the management API via the bus.

Comment: The requirement for a public IP for stv2 is listed on the [Connect to a virtual network using Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2#prerequisites) page: "A Standard SKU public IPv4 address. The public IP address resource is required when setting up the virtual network for either external or internal access. With an internal virtual network, the public IP address is used only for management operations."

Comment: Agreed that the APIM documenation includes the requirement, but the requirement is not manifest in the API (otherwise it would error out at deploy time), nor in the Terraform documentation.  One thing I would like to advocate is that Terraform providers should include a link to the platform documentation for each resource or data source that they define.  This could be handled in the API schema.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management#min_api_version), using the same sample and provider the `azurerm provider version 3.0.0`.
We have created an APIM instance(of developer sku). Post the creation we are able to see the platform version value as stv2 as shown in the below image here.

[image]

If you are using the `azurerm provider version 3.0.0` also if you are facing the issue I would suggest you create the API management instance using `azapi` provider.

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service?pivots=deployment-language-terraform) for more information on how to create APIM instance using `azapi provider` and also you can specify the specific resource provider **api version** in azapi provider.

Comment: I tried it right now, still creates stv1. My APIM is in internal mode. I use an existing VNET to deploy to

Comment: Is there a specific setting that creates an internal APIM in stv2? I've not set the public ip addresses property and I have no zones.

Comment: Looks like if you have not specified public_ip_address_id the default is stv1 if you use a vnet: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/compute-platform-versions-for-azure-api-management-service/ba-p/2836971